# Is there border checking when traveling between Norway and Denmark?

Tags: schengen, borders, norway, denmark

I will be visiting Norway and Denmark on my next trip, and I was curious if there is border control when traveling by car or train or not. I'm non-European holding short-term Schengen.

Comment: Can you add detail on how you plan to get to Denmark form Norway? Via ferry? or by driving through Sweden and across the bridge to Denmark?

Comment: So sorry. I somehow missed this. Most likely train through Sweden

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, as Norway and Denmark as both part of the Schengen area, a [passport should not be required](http://norwaytoday.info/travel/not-need-passport-cross-borders-nordic-countries/) - however at the time of writing (Jul 2017) security measures are still increased and border control checks in force between many of the Nordic countries.

If you *travel by train* (without ferry crossing): you'll be traveling from Norway via Sweden to Denmark - [border controls were in force until recently](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-39784715) between Sweden and Denmark with a passport check taking place on the train. While these have ended, spot checks do still happen frequently (form personal experience).

*Traveling by car*, you will need to either take the ferry from Norway to Denmark or drive through Sweden. Driving through Sweden the situation is similar as when going through Sweden by train.

*Taking the ferry* (whether with or without vehicle, i.e. by car or taking trains to and from the ferry), you will need to carry some form ID (incl. date of birth and photo - exact details see ferry operators [ColorLine](https://www.colorline.com/denmark-norway/ferry-hirtshals-kristiansand), [fjordline](https://www.fjordline.com/en/reisevilkar/), [StenaLine](https://www.stenaline.nl/en-GB-nl/FAQ/preparing-your-journey/travel-documents)) and it will be checked.

In conclusion: some of the border controls re-introduced in 2015 during the refugee crisis may have been abolished, but you're still likely to face an ID check - be it as a definite on the ferry or when encountering one of the very frequent spot checks on trains or when crossing borders by car.

Comment: Of course, even some people travelling by train may opt to take the ferry for whatever reason.  Ferries are not limited to people bringing a car.

Comment: @gerrit very true; especially if going to Jutland (Jylland in Danish) and not wanting to drive, taking trains and the ferry avoids a very long detour through Sweden and Zeland (Sjælland in Danish). I modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Just to confirm: going from Denmark to Sweden by bus via [Øresund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98resund_Bridge) you will be checked docs. There are total checks there.